# Leaflet .on() Eventlistener with markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, event-handling, leaflet

So I have a js file to implement a leaflet map in my blade file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  const container = document.getElementById('kkpAllMap')
  if(container) {
    var coordinates = $('#kkpAllMap').data('coordinates')
      
    const kkpAllMap = L.map(
      'kkpAllMap',
      {
        center: [11.5639911, 104.909288],
        zoom: 13,
      }
     
    )
    
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 50,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: mytoken
    }).addTo(kkpAllMap);

    var kkpnIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '/icons/kkpIcon.png',
  
      iconSize:     [38, 65], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor:   [19, 64], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor:  [-5, -56] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });

    var markers = []

    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

      var marker = L.marker(
        [coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2]], 
        {icon: kkpnIcon}
      )
        .addTo(kkpAllMap)
        .on('click', {foo: "bar"}, clickZoom);
        
      markers.push(marker)
    }

    function clickZoom(e) {
      kkpAllMap.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),15);
      console.log(e.data.foo)
    }
    
  }
  
    
})
```

when I click on each markers, i want to log the parameter (foo) that I passed to my function. Instead, it gave me this error:

**leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: a.fn.call is not a function**

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Event handler functions as defined by Leaflet receive only one parameter, the event (do read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#evented). Passing `{foo: 'bar'}` while attaching an event handler does **not** make that event handler receive any parameter `foo`. You might want to use closures instead.

Comment: I see, thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me!**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  const container = document.getElementById('kkpAllMap')
  if(container) {
    var coordinates = $('#kkpAllMap').data('coordinates')
      
    const kkpAllMap = L.map(
      'kkpAllMap',
      {
        center: [11.5639911, 104.909288],
        zoom: 13,
      }
     
    )
    
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 50,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: mytoken
    }).addTo(kkpAllMap);

    var kkpnIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '/icons/kkpIcon.png',
  
      iconSize:     [38, 65], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor:   [19, 64], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor:  [-5, -56] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });

    var markers = []

    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

      var marker = L.marker(
        [coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2]], 
        {icon: kkpnIcon}
      )
        .addTo(kkpAllMap)
        .on('click', function(e){
          clickZoom(e, {foo: 'bar'})
        })
        
      markers.push(marker)
    }

    function clickZoom(e, data) {
      kkpAllMap.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),15);
      console.log(data)
    }
    
  }
  
    
})
```

but i want to pass my partner_id, so I would do this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  const container = document.getElementById('kkpAllMap')
  if(container) {
    var coordinates = $('#kkpAllMap').data('coordinates')
      
    const kkpAllMap = L.map(
      'kkpAllMap',
      {
        center: [11.5639911, 104.909288],
        zoom: 13,
      }
     
    )
    
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 50,
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1,
      accessToken: mytoken
    }).addTo(kkpAllMap);

    var kkpnIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '/icons/kkpIcon.png',
  
      iconSize:     [38, 65], // size of the icon
      iconAnchor:   [19, 64], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
      popupAnchor:  [-5, -56] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });

    var markers = []

    for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

      var marker = L.marker(
        [coordinates[i][1], coordinates[i][2]], 
        {icon: kkpnIcon, partner_id: coordinates[i][0]}
      )
        .addTo(kkpAllMap)
        .on('click', clickZoom)
        
      markers.push(marker)
    }

    function clickZoom(e) {
      kkpAllMap.setView(e.target.getLatLng(),15);
      console.log(e.target.options.partner_id)
    }
    
  }
  
    
})
```